# Reason for calling super class constructor from subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance

According to *Introduction to programming using Python* by Liang

```
class(superclass):
```

**Gives you access to super class**

```
super().__init__()
```

**Instantiates the superclass so you can access its data fields and methods.**

This seems incorrect though; In the following code I access the super class using the first keyword `class(superclass)` but never initiate it using **super().__init__()** but I still have full access to all methods anyways.

If merely extending the parent class gives me access to its methods, what is the point of calling the parent classes constructor?

Reference: *Introduction to programming using Python*

**CODE:**

```
class GeometricObject:
    def __init__(self,color = "green",filled = True):
        self.__color = color
        self.__filled = filled

    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.__color = color

    def isFilled(self):
        return self.__filled

    def setFilled(self,filled):
        self.__filled = filled

    def __str__(self):
        return "Color: " + self.__color + \
               " and filled: " + str(self.__filled)

class square(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height
    def getWidth(self):
        return self.__width

    def setHeight(self,height):
        self.__height = height
    def setWidth(self,width):
        self.__width = width
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super provides more accurate details of what super is for

Comment: a = square(12,10);
a.getColor();

throws an error, because you didn't initialized base class.

Comment: the pythonic way would be to remove the functions getColor and setColor and rename __color to color, remove isFilled and setFilled and rename __filled to is_filled, remove getHeight and setHeight and rename __height to height, and ... you know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that code didn't come from any introduction to Python book: it's horribly un-Pythonic.

But the answer to your question is that extending gives you access to the *methods*, but doesn't do any of the setup done in the superclass `__init__`. In your example, an instance of `square` will have access to the `getColor` method, but actually calling it will give an error because you never ran `GeometricObject.__init__` to set the value of `self.__color` in the first place.

Comment: Python doesn't call the superclass constructor automatically?

Comment: @clcto No, indeed not. Apart from any questions of implicit vs explicit, not calling it automatically gives you the freedom to decide if you want to call it at all, and at what point in the subclass method you do so. You might for example want to call it first, so that you modify some of the setup that it does; or last, so that you can set up some preconditions for it to operate on.

Comment: Thanks mate! Makes a lot of sense! How is this code un-Pythonic btw? I did get it out of this book, just wondering what is wrong with it. Thanks

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 Having unnecessary getters and setters (eg `getColor` & `setColor`) instead of using attributes (eg creating `self.color` in the `__init__` rather than `self.__color`) is generally seen as a Java-esque pattern. While getters/setters have their place, they're not required for _all_ attribute access and are actually more inefficient. See [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) for more info. It's also considered good form to capitalize class names to distinguish them from instances, so `Square` rather than `square`.